# Relation between interpretations and theorems

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Give a formula that is not a theorem of PCL (Predicate classic logic).

By the Robust theorem, a valid interpretation $\iff$ theorem in PLC.

Thus any formula $\phi$ that is $F$ under some interpretation $I$ won't be a theorem in PLC.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, but I think you mean ["*completeness*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem), not "robust."

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes you're right.